# Calendar and Time picker not opening in Kendo Grid when upgraded to Kendo 2020.1.219

Tags: kendo-ui, calendar, kendo-grid, kendo-datetimepicker, kendo-timepicker

When i am clicking on the calendar and clock icon in datepicker it is going to the start of the grid and none of the date or time picker is opening and in one case the icon is also not loading. this is happening when i have upgraded kendo from 2016.3.1118 to 2020.1.219

Comment: That's a lot of versions. Go through https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history , see how those pickers should be used now, and check if it's a reported bug at https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues .

Comment: @GaloisGirl Thanks for the references.Actually i provided the specific version name which is nothing but 2020 SP1 to which i am migrating. I went through the links but didn't find anything related to my issue because in my case the datepicker or Date/timePicker is not working when it is used inside the Kendo Grid otherwise it is working fine at other places. The  Datepicker is not showing only when used inside the Kendo Grid.